# JavaScript audio will not play when tab is not in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have a webpage that uses [JQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and I have an audio clip that plays when the coundown reaches zero.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<script>
$(function (){
    $('#Timer1Timer').countdown({until: +(28800), onExpiry: play_single_sound});
    $('#Timer2Timer').countdown({until: +(172800), onExpiry: play_single_sound});
    $('#Timer3Timer').countdown({until: +(10), onExpiry: play_single_sound});
});
function play_single_sound() {
    document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
}
</script>
<audio id="audiotag1" src="audio/alert.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

The audio plays just fine when I have the page open in it's own window and I'm using a separate window to view another page. However, if I have a different tab open and active in the same window, the audio will not play when the countdown completes.

Any sort of assistance or explanation would be wonderful!

Comment: I strongly suspect this is browser-based. Many browsers susend javascript  or other features execution when the page is not in focus, especially on mobile devices to save up some power. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 40.0.2214.111 (latest)

Comment: Why don't you just try `setTimeout(play_single_sound, 5000 )` ? Do you need a plugin to replace javascript's timeout?

Comment: Jeremy, setTimeout(...) did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a plugin to replace javascript's native `setTimeout`. Try `setTimeout(play_single_sound, 5000)`